# C++ "Error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object"

Tags: c++

I'm trying to include `experiencecalculator` from a class but I get this **`Error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object`**.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include "ExpCalc.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Pick which calculator you would like to use by typing the correct "
            "number.\n";
    cout << "1. Experience Calculator" << endl;
    // cout << "" Insert other calculators and there number here.
    // cout << ""
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1) {
        ExpCalc::ExperienceCalculator;
    }
}
```

The class I am taking it from is:

ExpCalc.h

```
class ExpCalc
{
public:
    ExpCalc();
    int ExperienceCalculator;
};
```

ExpCalc.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ExpCalc.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

ExpCalc::ExpCalc() {}
int ExperienceCalculator() {
    double timetotal;
    double timeperinv;
    double xptotal;
    double xpitem;
    double amount;
    double perinv;
    double totalinv;
    double costper;
    double costtotal;

    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("Runescape Skill Calculator"));

    cout << "=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=Runescape Skill "
            "Calculator=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "How much experience do you want to get?" << endl;
    cin >> xptotal;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "How much does it cost per item?" << endl;
    cin >> costper;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "How much experience do you get per item?" << endl;
    cin >> xpitem;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "How many items can you process in one inventory?" << endl;
    cin >> perinv;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "How long does it take to process one inventory of items?" << endl;
    cin >> timeperinv;

    system("CLS");

    amount = xptotal / xpitem;
    totalinv = amount / perinv;
    timetotal = totalinv * timeperinv;
    costtotal = amount * costper;

    cout << "=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=Runescape Skill "
            "Calculator=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=" << endl;

    cout << endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << fixed;
    cout << "The amount of items that you will need to process is: \n" << amount
         << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The total amount of inventories to process all items is: \n"
         << totalinv << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The total time it will take to complete processing all items is:\n"
         << timetotal << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The total cost of the items will be: \n" << totalinv << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The total amount of inventories to process is: \n" << totalinv
         << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+==+=+==+=+==+=+==+=+==+=+=+=+=+=+=+="
            "+=+=+=+=+=+=+=" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
};
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Does nobody actually try to learn programming languages anymore?

Comment: Your problem is exactly what the error message says. There is not much more that we can say.

Comment: check a tutorial on structures/classes. you're mixing up [static members with instance members](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/#static_members)

Comment: In addition to the static/non-static issue, you've declared `int ExperienceCalculator` as a variable and not as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your H file describes ExperienceCalculator as int field. Your CPP file describes ExperienceCalculator as a free function (even not a method of ExpCalc). So I suspect that you have to do the following amends:

- H file:

  ```
  int ExperienceCalculator(); // parenthesis to be added
  ```
- CPP file:

  ```
  int ExpCalc::ExperienceCalculator() { // class name ExpCalc to be added
  ```
- main file:

  ```
  if (choice == 1) {
      ExpCalc exp_calc; // instantiate the class
      exp_calc.ExperienceCalculator(); // make a call to non-static method
  }
  ```

Alternatively, you can make the method as static but let make one step at a time. Happy coding!